# How to Adjust Feature Weights in Random Forest Model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am utilizing Scikit-Learn's Random Forest library, and I wanted to know if it is possible to change the feature weights, so specific features have more impact. I went through the Random Forest documentation, but I only see weight change for classes which I am not interested in.

Is there another way to do this other than rewriting the code itself? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I have an explainable framework that tells me which features have the most impact on the output. Once I get this output, I am trying to change the feature weights of my random forest model to see if the accuracy gets improved.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you are not supposed to do this, because the algorithm itself is better at deciding which feature is more important by calculating Gini impurity at each decision tree. If you want to improve the model, I recommend trying boosting models instead of bagging (random forest). XGBoost, LightGBM, CatBoost are all good choices, personally I like to use CatBoost, because it is the newest algorithm in boosting and offers superior results.

Answer (score -2):

Try some hyper-parameter techniques like RandomizedSearchCV and GridSearchCV from sklearn.model_selection